# WordPress custom theme, Why is my content not showing on page

Tags: php, wordpress

My pages are not showing any content on them other then the header and footer I think its something to do with the way i am laying out my  but don't really know.

index.php and page.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: `<?php echo the_content(); ?>`?

Comment: you can compare your theme to this one [here](https://github.com/taniarascia/startwordpress) or you post some more code here

Comment: @smoqadam [the_content](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/) does not need echo. `get_the_content` needs an echo.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot `while` statement.

Here's how your code should look:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) :  the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```